# Propiedad formatter en una grafica de echarts para añadir un link

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

tengo el siguiente código de js para generar una grafica, pero al definir las propiedades del label uso `formatter: function (params) { return "<a href='https://google.com'>"+ params.name +"</a>" ;},` para regresar el nombre con propiedades html (hice lo mismo con el tooltip y ahí funciona) pero para el label me regresa `<a href='https://google.com'> NAME</a>` como texto plano

Estoy declarando algo mal o hay alguna otra forma de vincular un objeto de la grafica a un enlace para que se abra al dar clic en él.

Estoy usando echarts

```html
{
              name: 'NAME',
              tooltip: {
                rich: true,
                formatter: function (params) {
                    // Personaliza el contenido del tooltip según tus necesidades
                    return '<div style="border:  solid green; background-color: #333; padding: 1px; color: white; width: 100%;">' +
                        '<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 5px;">' + params.name + '</div>' +
                        '<div style="color: #f4f4f4;">ESTADO: <span style="color: ' + PARAMS.Color.none_color + ';">-</span></div>' +
                        '<div style="color: #f4f4f4;">LOGS: <span style="color: ' + PARAMS.Color.none_color + ';">-</span></div>' +
                        '<div style="color: #f4f4f4;">INFO: <span style="color: ' + PARAMS.Color.none_color + ';">-</span></div>' +
                        '</div>';
                },
              },
              symbol: 'image://https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/106/106840.png',
              x: 900,
              y: 0,
              symbolSize: 35,
              label: {
                formatter: function (params) { return "<a href='https://google.com'>"+ params.name +"</a>" ;},
                rich: true,
                show: true,
                position: 'right',
                color: PARAMS.Color.none_color,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: 'lighter',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              },
              
            },
```

Muchas gracias